# Is my representation of $\varphi$ Work function correct?

Tags: energy, photons, electrons, coulombs-law, photoelectric-effect

I am a middle-school so my understanding of physics may not be as solid as you professional physicists but never the less thought its worth a try to learn more.

I read about photo-electric effect by Albert Einstein but never really read the complete math, as I wanted to see how far I could come to deriving the real equations of Photon-electric effect. All I know about the the effect is if the energy of photon is high enough, you may be able to eject an electron from the target atom.

Before I show my own thought process - I did this because it may help me not only understand concepts such as work functions and such better.

So here is my though process:

I thought that since $1$ joule of Energy ($E$)is equal to $1$ newton meter (measurement of force), we can say that force will also be binding energy of any object. Then I said that since there must be a force on an electron for it to orbit around the nucleus I used the coulomb law to get:
$$f = k_e\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}\therefore E_p = k_e\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2} $$

As we know this we must say that the above $E$ is the $\varphi$ as its the work function.

Now that said, we can say the energy of any given photon ($E_p$) must be greater than $\varphi$ so we can say $E_p < \varphi$, as if it is smaller than $\varphi$ then the coulomb force might just pull it back into its orbit.

As $E_p$ is greater than $\varphi$ we can say that the electron can escape the coulomb force of attraction therefore we could say that overall energy of the electron is $$\Delta{E} = E_p - \varphi$$

My question is that could $$\varphi = k_e\frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$$ if not why not? Because in my mind, I feel like we must over-come that attractive force in order to be able to eject a electron obviously ignoring the weak nuclear force that repels.

Next question is why doesn't a proton or neutron eject out? Why is it always the electron? Please ignore my question if you feel like I had no idea of physics as this is just an middle-school students poor attempt at formulating the photo-electric basis.

Comment: "since 1 joule of Energy (E)is equal to 1 newton" this is incorrect, force and energy are entirely different concepts

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Sorry, I mean 1 newton meter